# Bootstrap Masonry

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I have following code

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="post col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x380" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x380" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x380" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x380" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" />
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ku2cF/

but the first 2 elements (140x140) are wider then the 380x380 block below. For the first row it works, but the next 140x140 is only a single one...

When I set a fixed width (prefer not too) on the '#posts' then the blocks align correctly. but still I don't get the required results...

http://jsfiddle.net/ss6HF/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="post col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x380" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x380" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x380" />
    </div>
    <div class="post col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x380" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ku2cF/5/)

Comment: Of course this will work. But shouldn't it work in a more random order?